# ftp_put uploading zero byte files

Tags: php, ftp, localhost, remote-server

I'm make a quick PHP script to run locally on our computers in the office. The idea is so we can manage a competition from our office without allowing online access. The FTP upload is so we can upload the file to our FTP account.

I've got the following HTML form code:

```
<form method="post" id="new_competition" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <?php if(isset($error)){ echo "<p class='error'>$error</p>"; } ?>
            <?php if(empty($done)){ ?>
                <h1>Love Hearts Competition Entry</h1>
                <label>Opening Date: </label><input type="date" name="opening_date" value="<?= $opening_date; ?>" placeholder="Opening Date" required>
                <label>Closing Date: </label><input type="date" name="closing_date" value="<?= $closing_date; ?>" placeholder="Closing Date" required>
                <label>Title: </label><input type="text" name="title" value="<?= $title; ?>" placeholder="Competition Title" required>
                <label>Question: </label><textarea name="question" placeholder="Competition Question" required><?= $question; ?></textarea>
                <div class="answers">
                    <?php if(!empty($answers)){
                        foreach ($answers as $answer) {?>
                            <div class="answer"><label class="answer_label">Answer: </label><input type="text" name="answer[]" value="<?= $answer; ?>" placeholder="Answer text" required/><div class="remove_answer">X</div></div>
                        <?php } 
                    } else { ?>
                    <div class="answer"><label class="answer_label">Answer: </label><input type="text" name="answer[]" value="" placeholder="Answer text" required/><div class="remove_answer">X</div></div>
                    <?php } ?>
                </div>
                <div class="add_answer">Add another answer</div>
                <label for="terms">Terms &amp; Conditions File</label><input type="file" name="terms" placeholder="Terms &amp; Conditions File" required />
                <input type="submit" value="Add Competition" name="submit" id="submit" />
            <?php } else { ?>
                <p class='done'>Successfully added competition</p> 
            <?php } ?>
        </form>
```

And, as you can see, I have used the proper enctype.

My PHP Code is as follows:

```
if($_POST['submit']){

    $opening_date = $_POST['opening_date'];
    $closing_date = $_POST['closing_date'];
    $title = $_POST['title'];
    $question = $_POST['question'];
    $answers = $_POST['answer'];
    $terms = $_FILES['terms']['name'];
    $tmp = $_FILES['terms']['tmp_name'];

    $date_diff = (date_diff(date_create($opening_date), date_create($closing_date)));
    if(!$date_diff->invert){
        if(count($answers) > 1){
            $ftpCon = ftp_connect($host_ip);
            $ftpLogin = ftp_login($ftpCon, $host_login, $host_pswd);
            $remoteURL = '/public_html/competition_terms/'.$terms;

            // Upload the file!
            $ftpUpload = ftp_put($ftpCon, $remoteURL, $tmp, FTP_BINARY) or die("Unable to load upload file");


            if($ftpUpload){
                $answers_json = json_encode($answers);

                $db = mysql_connect($db_host, $db_user, $db_pwd) or die('cannot connect to db: '.mysql_error());
                $db = mysql_select_db('lovehear_competitions') or die(mysql_error());

                $query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO competitions (opening_date, closing_date, title, question, answers, terms) VALUES ('$opening_date', '$closing_date', '$title', '$question', '$answers_json', '".str_replace("public_html/", "", $remoteURL)."')") or die(mysql_error());
                $done = true;
            } else {
                $error = "Unable to upload file.";
            }
            ftp_close($ftpCon); 
        } else {
            // Only one answer
            $error = "You must give more than one answer";
        }
    } else {
        // Closing date before opening date
        $error = "You must have a closing date that ends after the opening date.";
    }
}
```

The file is created on my server, under "public_html/competition_terms/" but the file contains zero bytes.

Does anyone know why? I can't seem to see any useful help online and the PHP Docs don't seem to mention any restriction for local to remote uploading.

Comment: You have an extra quote in your `ftp_login` call. Is that actually there?

Comment: Whoops, I've desensitised the information, forgot to take that quotation mark out.

Comment: the `ftp_put` returns `true`, correct? Is `$_FILES['terms']['error']` also `0`?

Comment: ftp_put returns true and $_FILES['terms']['error'] is int(0)

Answer (score 0):

I think I solved it by restarting MAMP server.